# Automatic deployment of static content to apache

Tags: apache-2.2, deployment

I've got 8 apaches serving the same static content in different datacentres. Basically until now they were two and it was easy synchronizing them manually. However, they are now 8 and I would like to automate the deployment - they are serving only static content (images,html).

Is there any way I can deploy to every single one of them with few clicks?

THanks

Comment: There are plenty of ways. You can start researching as you'll have a long way to go from understanding your options to implementing a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric, Capistrano, rsync, git, are all options. Pick your poison.

Honestly, just play around with the above, find one that makes sense to you and go with it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we have SVN with packaged resources. Is there any way to get the resources from there and spread them over the machines?